# How can I pass objects into checkChanged event of a checkBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, object, checkbox

I am using WFA. I have two methods as follows:

```
public void method1(object abc)
{

}

public void method2(object abc)
{

}
```

I have a checkbox which can be checked or unchecked. If it is checked, it has to execute method1 , if unchecked, it has to execute method2. Both methods take object abc which comes from a different method.

After some research I figured, checkChanged event helps you do something like that. But the main issue I’m facing is not being able to pass the object *abc* into it to do the operation.

I also tried creating a new method that does the operation but passing object abc is what’s obstructing me.

I’m fairly new to programming so any idea/suggestion/help would be greatly appreciated. I’m pretty sure I’m overlooking something very simple.

Comment: Can you update your question with your `CheckChanged` event?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. But there is something missing from your question. What is your goal and your difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, your development environment and the data structures, as well as to share more code (no screenshot), images or sketches of the screen, and user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, consider reading the *[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)*.

Answer (score 0):

As how i see it, a checkbox has 2 important properies, "Checked" and "Checkstate".

The property "Checked" either returns true or false depending on if the checkbox has been checked or not, while the property "Checkstate" returns either "Checked" or "UnChecked"

Because you want to know whenever the checkbox is either checked or not, you should use the "Checked property" in a if statement:

```
public void method1(object abc)
{

}

public void method2(object abc)
{

}

if(fooCheckbox.Checked) {
method1(barObject)
}
else if (!fooCheckbox.Checked) {
method2(barObject)
}
```

You want to make sure that you pass a object to the variable and that it has been defined like so:

```
private object fooObject = new object();
```

Or define it into the constructor (which one fits best for you)

```
private object fooObject;

public barClass() {
fooObject = new object();
}
```

Hope this helps ;)